# inner class in wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6, wicket-6

I have 3 class A,B and C that B is in class A and C is in class B so C -> B -> A
and I named My html as A$B$C.html but I got this error :

```
Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent
Markup not found execption: ...
```

EDIT - for example like below:

```
public class A extends WebPage {
  public A(){
   ...
  }
  private class B extends AbstractColumn<T,String> {
    public B(){
     ...
     }
    private class C extends Panel{
      public C(){
        ... 
       }
    } 
  }
```

}

Comment: Put the classes in seperate files. Dont write your app in on file :)

Comment: :D thank you but in somehow I need it

Comment: I think the file should just be named A.html.

Comment: but It didn't work with A.html and had error

Comment: Hmm.. the same error or a different one?

Comment: Use a Fragment instead of a Panel. Put the Fragment markup in a.html

Comment: Show us a stacktrace.

Comment: Are you using <wicket:panel></wicket:panel> inside your file named A$B$C.html?

Comment: Yes. I seperated classes so It doesn't have problem anymore, but I still don't know whats the problem!